# Bootstrap/TagsInput Applying To All Form Fields/Not Displayed Correctly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I am having issues understanding how to properly apply Bootstrap/TagsInput to a form.

My goal is to have a form with one field using TagsInput and another field not using it.

There are two problems:

1. TagsInput seems to apply to any form field, not just the one I specify with data-role="tagsinput"
2. The tags don't stay inside of the form field as the form field is always "just ahead" of the tags.

Here is the code:

```js
        var citynames = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/citynames.json',
            filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
                return { name: cityname }; });
            }
        }
        });
        citynames.initialize();

        $('input').tagsinput({
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'citynames',
            displayKey: 'name',
            valueKey: 'name',
            source: citynames.ttAdapter()
        }
        });
```

```css
        .tt-query {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
        }

        .tt-hint {
        color: #999
        }

        .tt-menu {    /* used to be tt-dropdown-menu in older versions */
        width: 422px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        padding: 4px 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        }

        .tt-suggestion {
        padding: 3px 20px;
        line-height: 24px;
        }

        .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor,.tt-suggestion:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0097cf;

        }

        .tt-suggestion p {
        margin: 0;
        }
        
        .bootstrap-tagsinput{
            width: 40%;
            display: block;
        }
        
        .twitter-typeahead {
            width: 40%;
            display: block;            
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rainbow/1.2.0/themes/github.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="/items/create", method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title (should be no tags input):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tags"> Tags (should have tags input):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/gg6rwmwa/1/

I am new to JavaScript/CSS, so any guidance would be appreciated on where I doing things wrong.

I found a few similar stackoverflow questions, but none that seemed to hit on these two points exactly (and provided an answer).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For problem 1, your title info should not be inside the "form-inline" class.

Comment: You have not closed your tags properly. Which is some time a problem to run the javascript or jquery as it can't understand where your tag is ending and to which tag you are referring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You created two divs inside the "form-inline" class, and they both had action="/items/create" and method="post" attributes. To correct this, just separate the different fields like I show below.
2. That could be an issue with the CDN's you're using. I found a different one on [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tagsinput/) that seems to work pretty well. You can change it to suit your needs.

**Edit**

We also need to select the tags input form and do the relevant javascript processing inside of that. Every input field was becoming a tag input field because we forgot to add the $('#TagsInputForm') selector before doing our manipulations.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExample">No tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExample">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExample2">No tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExample2">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<form id="TagsInputForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Tag input</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control"
                   value="Tag" data-role="tagsinput" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TagsInputForm') {
        var citynames = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/citynames.json',
            filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
                return { name: cityname }; });
            }
        }
        });
        citynames.initialize();

        $('input').tagsinput({
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'citynames',
            displayKey: 'name',
            valueKey: 'name',
            source: citynames.ttAdapter()
        }}
        });
        });
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize I missed adding the the bootstrap-tagsinput.css reference, that fixed problem 2. However, I still am having issues with the both form fields having the tagsinput applied to it: https://jsfiddle.net/gg6rwmwa/4/ What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see that. You just need to tweak your javascript, it's an easy fix. See my edited answer

Comment: I think I see the issue. I was not understanding the jQuery scoping via that 'input' parameter. Your fix is almost correct, it just doesn't do the query of other tags (in the original if you typed a "L" it would bring up Los Angles, etc.), but I think I can figure that out. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!